# Adding values in the same dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to add up values (percentage changes) within the same dataframe column to plot it later on. The best would be to save that to a new dataframe.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
Date          Value 1   Value 2   Value 3   Value 4                               
2019-10-15        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-10-16  -0.000140 -0.001530 -0.005559 -0.008081
2019-10-17   0.006447  0.002043 -0.002396 -0.003360
2019-10-18  -0.006127 -0.001359 -0.003802 -0.007357
2019-10-21   0.003082  0.004424  0.004620  0.008749
```

I'd like to add up each column, e.g., for `Value 4`:

```
  Value 4
-0-008081  (Row 1)
-0,011441  (Row 1 + Row2)
-0,018798  (Row 2 + Row 3)
-0,010049  (Row 3 + Row 4)
```

I know about the shifting functionality, but not good enough to use it for that purpose.

*To add:
It is not meant to just shift the dataframe once and sum up the values. I need to add the next value to the result of the already added value after the shift*

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the dataframe, and add it back to the original dataframe, you may need to use `fillna(0)` to replace `NaN` values by zero before summing the dataframes up.

```py
>>> df+df.shift().fillna(0)
             Value 1   Value 2   Value 3   Value 4
Date                                              
2019-10-15       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-10-16 -0.000140 -0.001530 -0.005559 -0.008081
2019-10-17  0.006307  0.000513 -0.007955 -0.011441
2019-10-18  0.000320  0.000684 -0.006198 -0.010717
2019-10-21 -0.003045  0.003065  0.000818  0.001392
```

**UPDATE**:

Based on your comment, it seems that you need to use `cumsum` on row axis:

```py
>>> df.cumsum()
             Value 1   Value 2   Value 3   Value 4
Date                                              
2019-10-15       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-10-16 -0.000140 -0.001530 -0.005559 -0.008081
2019-10-17  0.006307  0.000513 -0.007955 -0.011441
2019-10-18  0.000180 -0.000846 -0.011757 -0.018798
2019-10-21  0.003262  0.003578 -0.007137 -0.010049
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is resulting just in one addition. So the first value (line 2: -0.011441 is correct. But the third line is already wrong, because it would calculate the addition of the initial dataframe and not with the one after the first shift.
Should be: -0.011441 + -0.007357 and not -0.003360 + -0.007357

Comment: @SljjnX, see the updated answer

Comment: what you want is `df.cumsum()`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I looked for! Thank you!